# How do I Remove a GameObject and add Different Types of objects In unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Ive been messing around in Unity3D and I've come along a Obstacle
That I can't jump.
Im trying to make a script That allows
me to Place And Remove GameObjects and Im also trying to create ui so I can select between different types of Objects.

Thanks in advance! 
http://pastebin.com/G8pz4ufr

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CubePlacer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Grid grid;

    private void Awake()
    {
        grid = FindObjectOfType<Grid>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                PlaceObjectNear(hitInfo.point);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo))
            {
                RemoveObjectNear(hitInfo.point);
            }
        }
    }

    public void PlaceObjectNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
    {
        var finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
        GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube).transform.position = finalPosition;
    }
    public void RemoveObjectNear(Vector3 clickPoint)
    {
        var finalPosition = grid.GetNearestPointOnGrid(clickPoint);
        GameObject.Destroy(GameObject, PrimitiveType.Cube);
    }
}
```

Comment: So what is the question? What exactly you are trying to do here? It would be appropriate to let others know what you did in script and where you are stuck. There is not enough information to go around. What kind of object you want to add to grid?

Comment: So I want to make a top down Bunker-Builder game and I was trying to add a selection of different walls so I managed to place a Basic Cube on a grid, Im struggling to remove the block I placed and I'm struggling to add a selection of walls, like having ui with 4 buttons and each time you press one of four buttons it switches to the corresponding block. Thank you for responding!

Comment: Not sure this is typo or a deliberate error in your code but I would like to point out `GameObject.Destroy(GameObject, PrimitiveType.Cube);` you cannot destroy a object without a reference to it. I can see only two override method to destroy & non of them have anything for PrimitiveType.Cube. If you intend to destroy the gameobject then just directly say **Destroy("your object to delete")** this will directly destory it while **Destroy(object, time)** will destory the object after specified delay.

Comment: Excuse me but im very new to code. How would I delete a specific block if I spawn a cube every time I press left mouse click. If I sound confusing which I probably am, I can send you the project files

Comment: Actually I think you better start learning Unity from scratch. I can do this for you but you wont learn anything if you don't put any efforts from you side. You need to keep the references of all objects you created. You can use a list/array to save references of grid elements. A List or array of gameobjects should be enough to know which grid had which gamobject. `Gameobject A = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube)` **A** will have reference to gameobject which you can on mousebutton(1) call destroy. Without a reference in programming you cannot delete anything.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Im going to rethink what I want to do and I'm going to focus on learning C sharp